# Lists not slicing correctly

Tags: python

noob here.
I'm currently having trouble with slicing lists in python.
My current code is as follows.

```
lines = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']

lines[0:4] = ' _ '
print(lines)
```

and the output is

```
[' ', '_', ' ', '4', '5', '6']
```

sometimes it will even change the length of the list to something like 3 or 2..

Why is it doing this? I feel like it should be pretty straight forward..

Thanks for any help!

edit: Sorry if I was unclear, I was rushing to write this before driving to work. My desired output would be that all index positions eg. 0:5 would become the string ' _ '. Like so [' _ ',' _ ',' _ ',' _ ','   ','   ']
Hopefully, that clears it up a bit more

Comment: What were you expecting?

Comment: You asked to replace the first four elements with the three elements in your string.  It did that.

Comment: Seriously, what *were* you expecting? We can't tell you how to do the thing you wanted to do if we don't know what you wanted to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A slice can only be assigned to an iterable object. A string is unique in that it can be both a single object and and an iterable list of characters. When the slice assignment asks for an iterable, it gets the individual characters in your replacement string.

I was as surprised by this result as you were, but there is a logic behind it.

I think what you were expecting could be obtained with:

```
lines[0:4] = [' - ']
```

Edit: your question was unclear, with the edit it appears you wanted 4 elements replaced with 4 other elements. In that case the replacement must *also* contain 4 elements:

```
lines[0:4] = [' - '] * 4
```

Comment: @StephenRauch my guess was that the intent was to replace 4 string elements with a single string element.

Comment: @StephenRauch please don't say "I told you so", the edit just made to the question shows that you are indeed correct.

Comment: But he said he want the `' _  '` more than once?  And by the tone of response you are not having fun so will leave you in peace.  Cheers.

Comment: @StephenRauch all in good fun. Thanks for keeping me on my toes. Hopefully my final edit makes things good.

Comment: @StephenRauch Your method of fixing my list worked. Thank you! Sorry about the unclearness

Answer (score 0):

The string ' _ ' is really just an array of characters `[' ', '_', ' ']`.

Thus, `lines[0:4] = ' _ '` sets the first element of lines to be ' ', the second to be '_', and third to be ' '. This explains the behavior you are witnessing.

If you are trying to make the first three elements of the list be ' _ ', I would suggest just doing `lines[i] = ' _ '` for each i being the index you want to replace with that string. There's probably a one-line method of doing this if you use a library function.

```
for i in range(4):
     lines[i] = ' _ '
```

Comment: If you are going to try and answer an unclear question, you should go ahead and answer it.  How can you set the first four elements equal to `' _ '`?

Comment: @user2779450 So when you say lines[i], you mean to enumerate through it then?

Comment: @tarkoon Yes. I have edited my answer to include a coded example of this. The answers above by ravishankar chavare work as well.

Answer (score 0):

if You want to Replace Starting 4 element with _

then just try

```
lines = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']
for idx,value in enumerate(lines[0:4]):
    lines[idx]="_"
print(lines)
```

If You Want Single line Solution then Try this

```
lines = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']
lines=["_" if 0 <= idx <= 3 else v for idx,v in enumerate(lines) ]
print(lines)
```